# Having issue with ANTLR swallow_to_semi rule

Tags: java, antlr

I am trying to parse few sentences with ANTLR. I have written basic grammar for that.

Grammar says that each sentence can start either keyword 'KEYWORDTYPE1' OR 'KEYWORDTYPE2'
and every sentence ends with ';'. Only difference between sentence starting with 'KEYWORDTYPE1' and  'KEYWORDTYPE2' is that for 1st one i want to include whitespace as well and for 2nd one I want to skip all whitespace.

```
grammar Hello;

options {
language = Java;
output   = AST;
}

sentence
:
(
'KEYWORDTYPE1' swallow_to_semi_with_whitespace SEMI
| 'KEYWORDTYPE2' swallow_to_semi_remove_whitespace SEMI
)*
;

swallow_to_semi_with_whitespace : ~(SEMI )+ ;
swallow_to_semi_remove_whitespace : ~(SEMI )+ ;

SEMI :';' ;
ID : ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )+ ;
INT : '0'..'9'+;
NEWLINE :('\r'? '\n')*;

WS
:
( ' ' | '\t')
 {
  $channel = HIDDEN;
 }
;
```

Expected generated tree :

```
null
 0 KEYWORDTYPE1
 1  
 2 TRUE
 3  
 4  
 5 111
 6  
 7 FALSE
 8  
 9 FALSE
 10  
 11  
 12 FALSE
 13  
 14 FALSE
 15  
 16 ;
 17 KEYWORDTYPE2
 18 TRUE
 19 TRUE
 20 TRUE
 21 TRUE
 22 TRUE
 23 TRUE
 24 ;
```

but with current grammar in both cases WHITESPACE are skiped.

Can you suggest what changes should i make to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is poorly phrased but if I understand, you want spaces sent to the parser.  if so, remove the action from WS.  Further this rule matches "nothing" as an option which is wrong:

`NEWLINE :('\r'? '\n')*;`

Comment: I want whitespace sent to parser for sentences starting with KEYWORDTYPE1 and whitespaces should be skiped for santences started with KEYWORDTYPE2.

Comment: See the expected generated tree for detail

Comment: Ah. Then you need to set some "state" information in the lexer like "saw KEYWORDTYPE1" and then allow/disallow whitespace using a semantic predicate.  Or if you don't care what's inside, just use .*? ';' to match in the lexer.

Comment: @TerenceParr  Is `@after` deprecated in ANTLR4? It's rarely mentioned in the latest definitive guide.

Comment: I haven't taken it out that I remember.

Answer (score 0):

I have made change in grammar to maintain state at Lexer by declaring

```
private boolean insideStatement = false;
```

and then added **@after** in **KEYWORDTYPE1  and SEMI** Lexer to change insideStatement  to **true** and **false** respectively.

and the last changes is that WS Lexer rule changed to emit to HIDDEN $channel based on insideStatement is set to true/false.

```
if (!insideStatement ) {
            $channel = HIDDEN;
        }
```

Below is complete grammar  :

```
grammar Hello;

options {
 language = Java;
 output   = AST;
}

@lexer::members {
private boolean insideStatement = false;
}

statement
  :
  (
    KEYWORDTYPE1 swallow_to_semi SEMI
    | KEYWORDTYPE2 swallow_to_semi SEMI
  )*
  ;

KEYWORDTYPE1
@after {
insideStatement = true;
}
  :
  'KEYWORDTYPE1'
  ;

KEYWORDTYPE2
  :
  'KEYWORDTYPE2'
  ;

swallow_to_semi
  :
  ~(SEMI )+
  ;

SEMI
@after {
insideStatement = false;
}
  :
  ';'
  ;

ID
  :
  (
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
  )+
  ;

INT
  :
  '0'..'9'+
  ;

NEWLINE
  :
  ('\r'? '\n')* 
                {
                 $channel = HIDDEN;
                }
  ;

WS
  :
  (
    ' '
    | '\t'
  )

   {
    if (!insideStatement ) {
        $channel = HIDDEN;
    }
   }
    ;
```